# python speech recognition listen in background is not giving errors or output

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I'm trying to have the speech_recognition module listen in the background when the user pushes a button made with py qt. I have the initialization and callback methods in a class, however when I try and listen to the microphone it doesn't seem to be registering anything, not even outputting errors.

````
import time

import speech_recognition as sr
def callback(recognizer, audio):
    try:
        print("Google Speech Recognition thinks you said " + recognizer.recognize_google(audio))
    except sr.UnknownValueError:
        print("Google Speech Recognition could not understand audio")
    except sr.RequestError as e:
        print("Could not request results from Google Speech Recognition service; {0}".format(e))


r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone()
with m as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)  
stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)

for _ in range(50): time.sleep(0.1)  

stop_listening(wait_for_stop=False)

while True: time.sleep(0.1)  ```

i want data to be sent the response as soon as it hears a word.  the response need to be printed in the console
````

Answer (score 0):

Define the default microphone with:

```
m = sr.Microphone(0)
```

This solved the unresponsiveness issue for me, seems to be forcing the microphone index to the default, even if sr should select it automatically.